# Vectorized programming with Matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a vector J which contains the row index of a vector.
<s>I would like to do the following code in a vectorized way :</s> I want to sum the duplicate values to the variable 'Mode' from the variable 'M'. I have `size(M)=size(J)`. This is my attempted code:

```
Mode=zeros(n,1);
for i=1:length(J)
    Mode(J(i))=Mode(J(i))+M(i);
end
```

I have tested with

```
Mode(J)=M
```

but the problem is that there are some duplicate index value in J.
How can I implement it correctly ?

Comment: @x1hgg1x Loops have gotten a lot faster in Matlab and I'd just leave this in a loop unless there are performance problems.

Comment: @MatthewGunn What you mean about increasing loop speed in Matlab? is it for 2015b ?

Comment: @MatthewGunn  The problem is that the size of J is pretty huge, and since this code is in an optimisation function I would like to improve run time.

Comment: You can use `accumarray`

Comment: Is `Mode(J(i))=Mode(J(i))+M(i);` supposed to be  `Mode(J(i))=Mode(J(i))+M(J(i));`?

Comment: @MatthewGunn No there is no error. I have size(M)=size(J).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`accumarray`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).

Have a look at this example:

```
J = [1 2 3 5 2 3].';
M = [1 1 1 1 1 1].';
Mode = accumarray(J, M, size(J)) 

Mode =

     1
     2
     2
     0
     1
     0
```

From the documentation:

> `A = accumarray(subs,val)` returns array `A` by accumulating elements of vector `val` using the subscripts `subs`. If `subs` is a column vector, then each element defines a corresponding subscript in the output, which is also a column vector. **The `accumarray` function collects all elements of `val` that have identical subscripts in `subs` and stores their sum in the location of `A`** corresponding to that subscript (`for index i, A(i)=sum(val(subs(:)==i)))`. Elements of `A` whose subscripts do not appear in `subs` are equal to `0`.

`size(J)` is used to make sure the dimension of `Mode` is the same as the dimension of `J`.

---

According to OP, the following code works:

```
A=accumarray(J,M); 
Mode(1:size(A))=A;
```